# Prevent Anonymous users info to be displayed in my views

Tags: views

I am making a list of users for views categorised in my table, however, there are users that are "Anonymous" and i dont want them to show up in the table. Is there any way of fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if a user is showing up in your users table (and thus users view), they must have an **account** on your system, so they would, at a minimum, be an 'Authenticated' user.  But they probably have no other roles other than 'authenticated'.

So try the following to filter them out of your users view:

1. Add a filter to your users view
   [image]
2. Select the 'User: Roles' filter and configure it as the screenshot below:
   [image]

Let us know if this worked.

p.s. I'm assuming you have Drupal 7 here, since that's what the screenshots are showing -- Views under Drupal 7, but it really helps to tag your question with the version of Drupal you're running.

Comment: I am using drupal 6, and I just fixed the issue, by filtering in the views, that if the Node:Name is Anonymous do not include in the list. Thanks for the help though, hope drupal 7 users will find it very useful. :)

Comment: Ooooh, I see.  These are nodes, rather than users.  In that case, they may indeed be anonymous.  Well, thanks for letting us know how you fixed it!

Comment: ohh sorry I meant user:Name is anonymous. I used it using users !

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter: `user ID (!= 0)`